# Unix monitoring portal

Tags: php, windows, unix, monitoring

I have 5 cluster servers on Unix[total of 10 unix boxes] and 5 windows servers, which I need to manage. I am looking at making a portal sort of thing, which would give me a snapshot of all the critical details, through the browser.[Mountpoint usages, cluster statuses, Oracle database health, tablespaces info etc ].

How do I go about this? I have apache installed and running on One Unix box. I started out with using the php's exec() command, and planned to use the remsh commands to fetch data from all servers, which I later realised wasn't working out.

How do I go about this? 
Any pointers please.
I strongly believe I can get this done through php, but I'm not that familiar with php,but would love to get working on it.

Help please!

remsh is not allowed on my environment, typically!

Comment: You might want to consider capturing the remote data to a centralized filesystem or small-ish db. Then you can show your boss, 'see it wasn't like this 3 months ago'. I used such a design to successfully lobby for increased servers, RAM and diskspace. (I no longer have access to that code, and it was a ksh solution anyway). Basically remote agents where lauched by ssh, run in a loop remotely and printed stats every X minutes back to the central server. You may be more luck on the unix part of your q by posting at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise that you go with an off-the-shelf solution and not try to write your own. This could be open source or proprietary. I have seen the free version of this tool and it can show much of what you described: [Zenoss](http://community.zenoss.org/index.jspa)

Comment: I work on a production environment and using external tools wouldnt be very much appreciated here, so I am looking at a custom solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I find that a rather foolish approach. If you're working in a production environment, the best thing you could do would be to use third-party tools, because they are almost certain to be more well tested than anything you can write in-house. Still, some people have that restriction. You might add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Nagios:

http://www.nagios.org/

You can also Google for "open source monitoring software"